# concatenate a column on one line depends on a id

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I've again a basic question :

If I do :

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, date, doctext, docline, from documentation where date in (02/14/2017)
```

doctext is a `char(80)` and I cannot change it. The problem of this columns is the size, I cannot save a value > 80 characters, If the doc is > 80 char, it will save two lines in SQL and upgrade the docline

So my result is, for example :

```
0 2017-02-14 this is a basic test to show you the result 0
1 2017-02-14 this is a new basic test to show you the result 0
2 2017-02-14 this is a  long basic test to show you the result 0
2 2017-02-14 when the documentation have multiple lines 1
```

What I'm trying to do is to concatenate doctext if the result have multiple line with the same id
So the result should be :

```
0 2017-02-14 this is a basic test to show you the result 
1 2017-02-14 this is a new basic test to show you the result 
2 2017-02-14 this is a  long basic test to show you the result when the documentation have multiple lines 1
```

Is it possible to concatenate a column on one line depends on a id ?
I'm trying with CASE like :

```
CASE WHEN docline > 0 THEN DOCTEXT ...
```

I don't know how can I spectify that I would like the next DOCTEXT

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT id, date,MAX(docline),
Ids=Stuff((SELECT ' ' + doctext  FROM documentation  d WHERE d.id=documentation.id
 FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '' )
 from documentation where date in (02/14/2017)
GROUP BY id,date
```

Comment: It's working only if I have one value in the documentation because if i have ;ore then 1 doc, it will concatenate all the documentation in 1

Comment: @FannyV What do you call documentation? .Try  to be more precise

Comment: documentation was for doctext. Thanks for your help ! I learn a new thing today (again)! I not working (yet) because my query is more complicate but you fixed and helped me a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

`For storing multiple lines you used the docline column but I didn't use it.`
`if you want you can add it.`

`I used two tables(MasterTable and DetailsTable)`

`Master Table:`

`ID    |   Date    |   DocText`
`-----------------------------`
`1      2017-01-14   Hello`
`-----------------------------`
`2      2017-03-18   Good Bye`
`------------------------------`
`3      2017-02-14   Hello Iran`
`------------------------------`
`4      2017-02-14   Good Bye Iran`
`------------------------------`

`DetailsTable:`

`ID    | DocText`
`---------------------------`
`3       How are you ?`
`---------------------------`
`4       See you ?`
`---------------------------`

`Use Test;`
`go`

`select mt.ID,mt.DocText + ' ' + ISNULL(dt.DocText,'') as DocText`
`from MasterTable mt`
`full outer join DetailsTable dt`
    `on mt.ID=dt.ID;`

`It works for multiple lines.`

`the result:`

`ID    |   Date   |    DocText`
`--------------------------------------------`
`1      2017-01-14   Hello`
`--------------------------------------------`
`2      2017-03-18   Good Bye`
`--------------------------------------------`
`3      2017-02-14   Hello Iran How are you ?`
`--------------------------------------------`
`4      2017-02-14   Good Bye Iran See you ?`
`--------------------------------------------`

Comment: thanks for your post but if I'm not wrong, I need to change the column tables? and create a new table? Like I told before, I cannot change my database structure